# selecting distinct same column values from non related tables

Tags: sql, database, oracle, t-sql

In my database, I have 3 tables that have 2 similar columns, Year and Month.  These tables aren't linked by anything.

What i want to do is select the distinct year and months from these tables.  So where table 1 contains:

2009 MAY (multiple times)
2008 NOVEMBER (multiple times)
2007 MAY (multiple times)

and table 2 and 3 contains:

2009 NOVEMBER (multiple times)
2009 MAY (multiple times)
2008 NOVEMBER (multiple times)
2008 MAY (multiple times)

I want to be able to do a select where it brings back a complete list of years and months from 2009 November to 2007 MAY.

I am struggling to work out the query.

Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT month, year
  FROM table1
UNION
SELECT month, year
  FROM table2
```

UNION will automatically return only distinct rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct year, month from table 1
union
select distinct year, month from table 2
order by year, month
```

The only problem with this is because your month is the alpha representation its not going to sort properly, but im sure oracle has a function to turn the string representation of a month into a numeric, and you can just sort by that instead.

Comment: Thanks alot.  should of guessed it'd be a union really.  For what i'm doing i can use an order by on month.  However, if someone were using all months of the year then they can do a decode